# Vectorized sum over slices of an array

Tags: arrays, r

Suppose I have an array of three dimensions:

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- array(rnorm(250),dim=c(5,10,5))
```

And I want to create a matrix of each row and layer summed over columns 4, 5 and 6. I can write do this like this:

```
apply(foo[,4:6,],c(1,3),sum)
```

But this splits the array per row and layer and is pretty slow since it is not vectorized. I could also just add the slices:

```
foo[,4,]+foo[,5,]+foo[,6,]
```

Which is faster but gets abit tedious to do manually for multiple slices. Is there a function that does the above expression without manually specifying each slice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for `rowSums / colSums` (fast implementations of `apply`)

```
colSums(aperm(foo[,4:6,], c(2,1,3)))

> all.equal(colSums(aperm(foo[,4:6,], c(2,1,3))), foo[,4,]+foo[,5,]+foo[,6,])
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, just beating me too it. I had a similar problem some months back and the `aperm()` solution helped there.

Comment: I knew about `rowSums()` and `colSums()` but they were giving unexpected results. `aperm()` indeed seems to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
eval(parse(text=paste(sprintf('foo[,%i,]',4:6),collapse='+')))
```

I am am aware that there are reasons to avoid `parse`, but I am not sure how to avoid it in this case.